# Google places autocomplete gives "Cannoat load results !"

Tags: android, api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I try to implement the google autocomplete feature inside my application and when I try searching it says: "Cannot Load results" and the log says E/Places: Error while autocompleting: NETWORK_ERROR.

I have acquired an api key, added the following permisions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And this is how I initialize places (in the google cloud platform the places api is enabled) :

```
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
```

Comment: Have you read [this page](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)?

Comment: Have you enabled billing on your project? Have you fully migrated to the new Places SDK for Android and to AndroidX? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start

Comment: Yes I can confirm I did all of that. I did it again after you have left this comment and still no answer.

Comment: I see, in that case can you please post your code implementation, manifest and build.gradle so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue by testing manually on my phone and then installing a new emulator. Thank you for your support !

Comment: Glad to hear! :) Consider posting & accepting your own answer to the question for the community's sake.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue by testing manually on my phone and then installing a new emulator. Thank you for your support !